# Prove: $\int_0^2 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{6\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-curves, beta-function

Prove:
$$
\int_{0}^{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\,\sqrt{\,{1 + x^{3}}\,}\,} =
\frac{\Gamma\left(\,{1/6}\,\right)
\Gamma\left(\,{1/3}\,\right)}{6\,\Gamma\left(\,{1/2}\,\right)}
$$

First obvious sub is $t = 1 + x^{3}$:
$$
\frac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{9}{\left(\,{t - 1}\,\right)}^{-2/3}\, t^{-1/2}\, \mathrm{d}t
$$
From here I tried many things like $\frac{1}{t}$, $t-1$, and more.  The trickiest part is the bounds! Reversing it from the answer the integral should be like
$$
\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}
x^{-2/3}\left(\,{1 - x}\,\right)^{-5/6}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
I'm not sure where the $1/2$ comes from and the $0$ to $1$ bounds.  Any idea or tip please ?.

Comment: Try the substitution $u=\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: @TomHimler Now I get to $$\frac{2}{3} \int_0^1 t^{-\frac{2}{3}} {\left(1+8t\right)}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \; \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: My bad, I made a dumb error.

Comment: May I ask where you found this integral?

Comment: @dxdydz https://tieba.baidu.com/p/4794735082

Comment: @Mo Qabar Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

***An elementary solution:*** Consider the substitution
$$t = \frac{{64 + 48{x^3} - 96{x^6} + {x^9}}}{{9{x^2}{{(4 + {x^3})}^2}}}$$
$t$ is monotonic decreasing on $0<x<2$, and $$\tag{1}\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^3}} }} = -\frac{{dt}}{{3\sqrt {1 + {t^3}} }}$$
this can be verified by explictly computing $(dt/dx)^2$ and compare it to $9(1+t^3)/(1+x^3)$. When $x=2, t=-1$, so
$$\int_0^2 {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^3}} }}dx}  = \frac{1}{3}\int_{ - 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {t^3}} }}dt} $$
I believe you now have no difficulty to solve last integral via Beta function.

---

***A conceptual solution:*** Consider the elliptic curve $E:y^2=x^3+1$, $P=(2,3),Q=(0,1)$ on $E$, $\omega = dx/y$ is the invariant differential on $E$. For the multiplication-by-$3$ isogeny $\phi:E\to E$, we have $3P=(-1,0), 3Q=O$. So $3\int_0^2 \omega \cong \int_{-1}^\infty \omega$ up to an element of $H_1(E,\mathbb{Z})$.

$t$ given above is the $x$-component of $\phi$ and $(1)$ is equivalent to $\phi^\ast \omega = 3\omega$.

The $P$ above is $6$-torsion, if we consider $4$ or $5$-torsion instead, we obtain
results like
$$\int_0^\alpha  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^3}} }}dx} = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{12 \sqrt{\pi }} \qquad \alpha = \sqrt[3]{2 \left(3 \sqrt{3}-5\right)} \approx 0.732 $$
$$\int_0^\alpha  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^3}} }}dx} = \frac{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{15 \sqrt{\pi }}\qquad \alpha = \left(9 \sqrt{5}+3 \sqrt{6 \left(13-\frac{29}{\sqrt{5}}\right)}-19\right)^{1/3}\approx 1.34$$

Comment: how in the world did you pull out that substitution?

Comment: This is probably the most "obvious" substitution I ever saw. Back to serious, how did you find it ?

Comment: @CSquared   How the substitution arises is explained in the "***conceptual solution***" below. For someone doesn't know much about elliptic curves, unfortunately he/she might simply need to accept the magical appearance of it. But once the substitution has been explicitly written down, every detail can be verified.

Comment: @pisco am inspired of what i saw and read, in addition to elliptic curves what context i should read to got your substitution ?

Comment: @adam I am not sure if there are contexts where the substitution arise more naturally than elliptic curve. But there is a wealth of theory behind such integral, such as theory of algebraic curves and elliptic functions.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  But how would I go about integrating $$\frac{1}{3} \int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}$$
We want the lower bound to be $0$ and upper to be $\infty$ I think, so I thought $u=t+1$ but that doesnt help.

Comment: @MoQabar   Split it into $(-1,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$. The former can be converted into beta function via $t\mapsto -t$. Latter is of course also convertible to beta.

Comment: +1 for the extremely magical solution. Your conceptual solution is beyond my reach but maybe someday I will be able to get it.

Comment: I'd love to see some sage code for how you generated those identities at the bottom! Can't quite figure it out myself.

Comment: @NicoA   Sage seems unable to generate torsion points in algebraic closure. Those bottom identities are obtained by solving equation $x(3P) = x(P)$ for $4$-torsion and $x(3P) = x(2P)$ for $5$-torsion using Mathematica.

Comment: @pisco Ah, that's also the problem I ran into. Glad I'm not  alone! But I wasn't aware you can do elliptic curve arithmetic with Mathematica - I'd love to see a sample of that code if possible.

Comment: @NicoA  I did not use Mathematica to do arithmetic on elliptic curve, the CAS was only used to find *radical* solutions of equations $x(3P) = x(P)$ and $x(3P) = x(2P)$.

Comment: I'm a little confused on extending your conceptual solution to the $4$-torsion case - using the point with x-coordinate $\alpha$, you have that $x(3P)=x(P)=\alpha$, so you just end up with the identity $3\int_{0}^{\alpha} \omega  = \int_{\alpha}^{\infty} \omega $. Where do you go from there?? Or am I missing something (I'm very new to elliptic curves)?

Comment: @TeaFor2 You're on the right track. You proved $4\int_{0}^{\alpha} \omega  = \int_{0}^{\infty} \omega$, and latter integral is beta function. Your reasoning still works for *the $5$-torsion given*, but there is a subtlety for other $5$-torsions.

Comment: @pisco Ah! It all clicked. Thank you. Out of sheer curiosity - could you guide me to some hints/terms to look into to understand the subtlety of the other $5$-torsion?

Comment: @TeaFor2  The subtlety is, for $5$-torsion $\alpha$, $3\int_{0}^{\alpha} \omega  = 2\int_{\alpha}^{\infty} \omega$ only holds modulo so-called "periods" of the elliptic curve. You have exact equality for the $\alpha$ given in my answer, but *equality* is in generally false for other torsions.

Answer (score 8):

***A hypergeometric solution***: Modulo Beta function $I_0=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+1}} \, dx=\frac{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$ one may evaluate $I_1=\int_2^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+1}} \, dx$ instead. Substitute $x\to\frac 1x$ and binomial expansion gives
$$I_1=\sqrt{2} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{2};\frac{7}{6};-\frac{1}{8}\right)=\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{3}} \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$
Where the last step has invoked the following [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777305) $$\, _2F_1\left(a,a+\frac{1}{3};\frac{4}{3}-a;-\frac{1}{8}\right)=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3 a} \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}-a\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}-a\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}-2 a\right)}$$

Computing $I_0-I_1$ gives the desired result.

---

Update: Hypergeometric method can also establish @pisco's result (the case of $4$-torsion)

> $$\int_0^\alpha  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^3}} }}dx} = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{12 \sqrt{\pi }} \qquad \alpha = \sqrt[3]{2 \left(3 \sqrt{3}-5\right)} \approx 0.732$$

Since by binomial expansion again, it equals $$\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) {_2F_1}\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{3},10-6 \sqrt{3}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(6 \sqrt{3}-9\right) \pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{3\ 3^{3/4} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}$$ due to certain transformation of hypergeometric series (see *Special values of hypergeometric series* by Akihito Ebisu). The rest are trivial.

Answer (score 5):

This is a late solution, after the structural solution of [pisco](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/257943/pisco) was already accepted, it also uses the elliptic curves intuition, and tries to give a "simpler substitution" and the way to obtain it. The substitution is
$$X = \frac{x^3+4}{x^2}\ ,$$
but let us see how first it was obtained free of charge, since this is the main point. I will give full details of the computations, CAS support, and show the pictures of the involved elliptic curve paths.

---

(1) *How to obtain the substitution?*

(The reader considering sage code annoying may please completely skip (1) and extract only the information that an isogeny killing the $3$-torsion point $(0,1)$
is used.)

The given integral can be seen as the integral of the invariant differential $dx/y$ on the path $\gamma$
from the point $P=(x_0,y_0)=(0,1)$ to
$Q=(x_1,y_1)=(2,3)$ on $E(\Bbb R)$, where $E$ is the elliptic curve given by the (affine) equation:
$$
E\ :\ y^2=x^3+1\ .
$$
In a picture:

[image: The real view of yy = xxx + 1]

Just for the protocol: This was obtained in sage via:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [0, 1])
sage: points = [E(P) for P in [ (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1), (2,3), (2,-3) ]]

sage: pic = E.plot(xmin=-2, xmax=3)
sage: for P in points:
....:     pic += point(P.xy(), size=40, rgbcolor=hue(0.75))
....: 
sage: pic
```

As the OP remarks, there would be no problem to compute the integral from $P=(0,1)$ to the infinity point using the substitution $t=x^3+1$ to introduce the beta function, but we integrate from $P$ to $Q$, and the same substitution leads to an "incomplete beta" value. So the problem is the upper integration limit $2$ corresponding to $Q$.

We would like to use an algebraic substitution and move $Q$ to a "simpler point" (possibly on some other elliptic curve).
Note that the points that appear have finite order, using sage to print this information...

```
sage: for P in points:
....:     print(f'The point {P.xy()} has order {P.order()}')
....: 
The point (-1, 0) has order 2
The point (0, 1) has order 3
The point (0, -1) has order 3
The point (2, 3) has order 6
The point (2, -3) has order 6
```

The idea to proceed is natural, we use the isogeny which "simplifies" the complicated torsion point $Q=(2,3)$ of order $6$. Note that $2Q=P$ on $E$:

```
sage: P, Q = E.point((0,1)), E.point((2,3))
sage: 2*Q == P
True
```

(So using the isogeny which "kills" $P$ will also "simplify" $Q$.)

We ask sage for this isogeny in the one-liner:

```
sage: phi = E.isogeny(kernel=P)
```

and let it give us its underlying information:

```
sage: phi
Isogeny of degree 3
    from Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 1  over Rational Field
    to   Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 - 27 over Rational Field
sage: phi.rational_maps()
((x^3 + 4)/x^2, (x^3*y - 8*y)/x^3)
sage: phi(P), phi(Q)
((0 : 1 : 0), (3 : 0 : 1))
```

This leads to a map $\phi:(x,y)\to\phi(x,y)=(X,Y)$ between the elliptic curves
$$
\begin{aligned}
E\ :\qquad && y^2 &= x^3+1\text{ and}\\
E'\ :\qquad && Y^2 &= X^3-27\text{ given by the passage}\\
&& X &=\frac{x^3+4}{x^2}\ ,\\
&& Y &=y\cdot\frac{x^3-8}{x^3}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
and the image curve is $Y^2=X^3-27$, the path $\gamma$ from $P$ to $Q$ on $E(\Bbb R)$ becomes the path $\gamma'$ from $P'=\infty$ to $Q'=(3,0)$ on $E'(\Bbb R)$.
I can plot only $Q'$ on $E'(\Bbb R)$...

[image: The real view of YY = XXX-27]

So we integrate alternatively the invariant differential form $dX/Y$ on the "upper branch" starting from $Q'=(3,0)$ to the infinity point.

Indeed, the above expressions $X,Y$ satisfy:
$$
\begin{aligned}
X^3-Y^2
&=\frac{(x^3+4)^3}{x^6}-\underbrace{y^2}_{x^3+1}\cdot\frac{(x^3-8)^2}{x^6}\\
&=\frac 1{x^6}
\Big[\ 
(x^9+12x^6+48x^3+64)
-
(x^9-15x^6+48x^3+64)
\ \Big]
\\
&=27\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

(2) *Using the substitution:*

We formally use $X=(x^3+4)/x^2$, $Y=y(x^3-8)/x^3$, and compute *formally*:
$$
\begin{aligned}
dX &= \left(x+\frac 4{x^2}\right)'\; dx
= \left(1-\frac 8{x^3}\right)\; dx
= \frac {x^3-8}{x^3}\; dx
\ ,\text{ so as expected}\\
\frac{dX}Y
%&=\frac {x^3-8}{x^3}\; dx\cdot\frac {x^3}{y(x^3-8)}\\
&=\frac{dx}y\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(The isogeny connects the invariant differentials.)
This gives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^2\frac {dx}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}
&=
\int_{\gamma\text{ from }(0,1)\text{ to }(2,3)\text{ on }E(\Bbb R)}
\frac{dx}y
\\
&=
\int_{\gamma'\text{ from }(3,0)\text{ to }\infty\text{ on }E'(\Bbb R)}
\frac{dX}Y
\\
&=
\int_{Y=0}^{Y=\infty}
\frac{d(Y^2+27)^{1/3}}Y
=\int_0^\infty \frac 23(Y^2+27)^{1/3-1}\; dY
\\
&\qquad\text{ (Substitution: $27t=Y^2+27$, $Y=27^{1/2}(t-1)^{1/2}$)}
\\
&=\int_1^\infty 
\frac 23\cdot 27^{-2/3}\; t^{-2/3}\; 27^{1/2}\; \frac 12(t-1)^{-1/2}\; dt
\\
&\qquad\text{ (Substitution: $u=1/t$)}
\\
&=\int_0^1 
\frac 13\cdot 3^{-2}\; u^{2/3}\; 3^{3/2}\; (1-u)^{-1/2}\; u^{1/2}\; \frac 1{u^2}\;du
\\
&= 3^{-3/2}\int_0^1 u^{1/6-1}\; (1-u)^{1/2-1}\;du
\\
&= 3^{-3/2}B\left(\frac 16,\frac 12\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

(3) *Note:*

The above value involving the beta function $B$ is equal to
$\frac 16B\left(\frac 16,\frac 13\right)$, use for this the multiplication theorem for the gamma function:

$$
\Gamma\left(\frac 13\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac 23\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac 33\right)
=(2\pi)\;3^{-1/2}\;\Gamma(1)\ .$$

Comment: Do you have any sources or recommendations for learning more about elliptic curves, namely the types you use here?

Answer (score 5):

Consider
$$
y^2=4x^3+4,g_2=0,g_3=-4
$$
The real period of $\wp(z)$ is
$$
\omega_1=\int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} \text{d}x
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{6}  \right ) }{2\sqrt{\pi} }
$$
And
$$
\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{2}  \right ) =-1
$$

---

We have the addition formula:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\wp(3z) = \frac{1}{4}\left [  \frac{\wp'(z)-\wp'(2z)}{\wp(z)-\wp(2z)} \right ]^2
-\wp(z)-\wp(2z)\\
&\wp(2z)=\frac{1}{4} \left [ \frac{\wp''(z)}{\wp'(z)}  \right ] ^2-2\wp(z)\\
&\wp(u+v)
=\frac{1}{4} \left [ \frac{\wp'(u)-\wp'(v)}{\wp(u)-\wp(v)}  \right ]^2
-\wp(u) -\wp(v)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $3z,2z,z$ is not at the period lattices.
Let $x=\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{6}  \right ) ,y=\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{3}  \right )$.And they have two relations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{4} \left [ \frac{\sqrt{4x^3+4}-\sqrt{4y^3+4} }{x-y}  \right ]^2-x-y  = -1\\
&y=\frac{9x^4}{4x^3+4} -2x
\end{aligned}
$$
Solve it and gives,
$$
\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{6}  \right )=2,
\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{3}  \right )=0
$$
So,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I:&= \int_{0}^{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3} } \text{d}x\\
&=2\left(\frac{\omega_1}{3} -\frac{\omega_1}{6} \right)\\
&=\frac{\omega_1}{3} 
\end{aligned}
$$

---

We have $\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{4}  \right ) =\sqrt{3}-1$,hence
$$
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3} -1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3} }\text{d}x
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{6}  \right ) }{12\sqrt{\pi} }
$$

---

We have
$t=\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{8}  \right ) =
-1+\sqrt{3} +\sqrt{3}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3} }  
+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3} }  }$,hence
$$
\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3} } \text{d}x
=\frac{5\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{6}  \right ) }{24\sqrt{\pi} }
$$

---

We have
$t=\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{12}  \right ) 
=2+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3} }$,hence
$$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3} } \text{d}x
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{6}  \right ) }{4\sqrt{\pi} }$$

---

We have
$
t=\wp\left ( \frac{\omega_1}{9}  \right ) 
=2^{1/3}
\left ( 16+3\cdot2^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{37+i\sqrt{3} }+
6\cdot2^{-1/3}\sqrt[3]{37-i\sqrt{3} }
 \right )^{1/3}\approx4.5707391614928...
$,hence
$$
\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3} } \text{d}x
=\frac{2\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{6}  \right ) }{9\sqrt{\pi} }
$$

---

If $t\ge0$,and
$$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3} } \text{d}x
=R\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{6}  \right ) }{\sqrt{\pi} }$$
where $R$ is rational with $0\le R\le\frac{1}{3}$.$t$ must be an algebraic number.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{2}{\dd x \over \root{1 + x^{3}}}}  =
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 + 8x^{3}}^{-1/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &
{2 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\,\bracks{1 + 8x}^{-1/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\color{red}{1/3}\ -\ 1}\,
\pars{1 - x}^{\color{#0f0}{4/3}\ -\ \color{red}{1/3}\ -\ 1}
\,\bracks{1 -\pars{\bf\color{red}{-8}}x}^{\,-{\bf 1/2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\,\mrm{B}\pars{\color{red}{1 \over 3},
\color{#0f0}{4 \over 3} - \color{red}{1 \over 3}}
\mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{\bf{1 \over 2},
\color{red}{1 \over 3};\color{#0f0}{4 \over 3};-8}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/3}\Gamma\pars{1} \over \Gamma\pars{4/3}}
\,\mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{\bf{1 \over 2},
\color{red}{1 \over 3};\color{#0f0}{4 \over 3};-8}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\large {\Large 2}\,\,\mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\!\!\!\pars{\bf{1 \over 2},
\color{red}{1 \over 3};\color{#0f0}{4 \over 3};-8}}
\approx 1.4022 \\ &
\end{align}
Step (\ref{1}): See the
[Euler Type Hypergeometric Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type).